# Drupal - Breadcrumb and 'In this section'

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, navigation, drupal-modules

I have  looked all over the Drupal site to find out how to view the breadcrumbs that the menu breadcrumb module installs, but no one else seems to be having the same problem as me, has any one come across the menu breadcrumb module in Drupal and knows how to use it?  Also is there a solution in Drupal again couldn't find an answer, in that you get a list of all the pages in a section of the site and list them on the page, in See Also kind of style?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks Sico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are two different questions. I am not familiar with the Menu Breadcrumbs module, but when in doubt, clear the cache.

If you want to list a lot of pages in the site, check out [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) (Glossary comes prepackaged), [Site Map](http://drupal.org/project/site_map), or a number of other modules. For recommendations of related content, check out [this comparison chart](http://drupal.org/node/323329), the [Recommender API](http://drupal.org/project/recommender), and more. It will be worth your while to check out [Drupalmodules.org](http://drupalmodules.org) to investigate what modules are available. I have only touched on a few off the top of my mind.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick read through the module, it seems like the module uses the drupal_set_breadcrumb() function, to alter the breadcrumb. That means that the reason you are not seeing the breadcrumbs shouldn't have anything to do with the module. If you deactivate it you should still have the problem. Many themes have the option to disable breadcrumbs altogether and some doesn't even implement them. My guess would be that your problem is located in your theme.